# Update a Mysql table from Select

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have the following select:

```
select a.TX , b.PSP_map as PSP_map_DC from psp_DC_CO_consol a 
left join psp_DC_CO_consol b on b.TX=a.TX
where a.source='CORE' and a.PSP_map is NULL and a.PSP<>'' and a.TX<>'' and a.StatusTX=1 
and b.PSP_map is not NULL
```

i Need now to update the column PSP_map with the 'PSP_map_DC' column from my select in the table psp_DC_CO_consol and only for the rows with source='CORE' and TX= TX from my select.

I have tried with no success.

Comment: What do you mean by "update"? Why not use an `UPDATE` query for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a self join in the `UPDATE` statement, like your query, but it should be an `INNER` join since you have the condition `b.PSP_map IS NOT NULL`:

```
UPDATE psp_DC_CO_consol a
INNER JOIN psp_DC_CO_consol b ON b.TX = a.TX
SET a.PSP_map = b.PSP_map
WHERE a.source='CORE' AND a.PSP_map is NULL AND a.PSP <> '' 
  AND a.TX <> '' AND a.StatusTX = 1 AND b.PSP_map IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery for the values when you make your update query:

```
update my_table set value = (select value from other_table where condition)
```

but you should make sure that the subquery return only 1 row